# Using jQuery to select unrelated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and writing a script to change the color of a certain element based on whether or not the element it lies upon has been selected. My first problem is I am not able to edit the html structure and the way the structure is formed is causing some problems for me. Basically this is the structure:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="teamNames">
        <span>Team 01</span>
        <span>Team 02</span>
    </div>
    <div class="teamBlocks">
        <div class="block 01">
            <div>Home</div>
            <div>0.65</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block 02">
            <div>Home</div>
            <div>0.65</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The team names have been absolutely positioned to lie over the blocks, so the content of the blocks looks like "Team Name    Home    0.65". 
When a block is selected its class becomes:

```
class="block 01 sel"
```

I am able to change the color of the "Home" and "0.65" text easily with CSS but changing the team name (Team 01/Team 02) is proving to be a lot more complicated and I am wondering if its possible to do this with or javascript or jQuery ?
Its also worth noting that the team names will never be the same so doing a selection based on the content is not possible

Comment: please show, that you tried so far!

Comment: I didn't get what you're trying to do..?

Comment: Are you looking for `$('.teamNames > span')`?

Comment: $('.teamNames span').get(whatever index here).text('whatever text here');

Comment: @TilwinJoy at least problem was with incorrect html code. But you fix it by adding ">" as edit, so maybe you solved problem. But not as answer - as edit

Comment: you have  not said if there is an event that is triggering the class change, or if the html page is loaded with those class definitions. This will have a lot of impact on how you go about this...

Answer (score 0):

To change a specific team, you will need to give them unique identifiers, for example:

```
<div class="teamNames">
    <span id="item1">Team 01</span>
    <span id="item2">Team 02</span>
</div>
```

No you change select the specific span elements using jQuery. For example you want to change Team 01:

```
$("#item1").text("New Team Name");
```

Hopefully this is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to find team element by selected block?
If yes you can use $.index function for getting index of selected team:

```
var currentBlock = $('.sel');
var indexOfCurrentBlock = $('.block').index(currentBlock);
if (indexOfCurrentBlock != -1) {
    var currentTeamName = $('.teamNames span').eq(indexOfCurrentBlock);
    currentTeamName.text('aaaa');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JRFv6/

Answer (score 0):

if I get the question right, you can change the names with jquery like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".teamNames span:first").html("hello world");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this looking for class="block 01 sel" if it is selected

```
$(".block").click(function(){
    $(".block").removeClass("sel");
    $(this).addClass("sel");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9f88h/3/)

Answer (score 0):

the way to change in elements not having id  without to change html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head> 
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="teamNames">
                <span>Team 01</span>
                <span>Team 02</span>
            </div>
            <div class="teamBlocks">
                <div class="block 01">
                    <div>Home</div>
                    <div>0.65</div>
                </div>
                <div class="block 02">
                    <div>Home</div>
                    <div>0.65</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(".teamNames span:eq(0)").html("New-Team-Name<br>");
            $(".teamNames span:eq(1)").text("---- New Team Name");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```